# Regex that should parse math expressions doesn't work properly

Tags: java, regex

I need to get only math expressions from my string.
I wrote the regex `[^[0-9]+([\\+\\-\\*\\/][0-9])*]` but it for some reason it also parses just `*`, `/`, `-`, `+` signs when they're not adjacent to number.

Example: I have string:
`"hrere 4ffwf43 12/6rr 4+2 efwfwf5343-3+5 rgwrgr54*2 rwe/fwef44efw 41+4"`

And result of replacing all matched string with empty string is:

`"   4    43 12/6   4+2       5343-3+5       54*2    /    44    41+4"`

But I don't want the single `/` to be parsed

How can I improve my regex?

```java
String regex_to_get_expressions =
"[^[0-9]+([\\+\\-\\*\\/][0-9])*]";
String to_ch = " ";
String result = to_delete_from.
replaceAll(regex_to_get_expressions, to_ch);
```

Comment: While the question is mainly about regex, it would help to see your code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: I don't really understand if you're trying to match numbers grouped by mathematical operators or the opposite. If it's the former, you can try something like `\d+\s*(?:[-+*/]\s*\d+)+`. Please look up what character classes are, too. www.regular-expressions.info has good explanations.

Comment: I try to match everything that is not math expression and then delete it ,so that only math expressions are left in the string

Comment: You could use alternation to capture the expressions you want to keep and match the characters you want to get rid of, then substitute by the capturing group, which is going to be empty for the matches that are not captured. Something like `(\d+(?:\s*[-+*/]\s*\d+)+)|\S` substituted by `$1`. You'll have to escape the slashes for Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only care about the math expressions, it would be easier to match them instead of matching the opposite and then removing it:

`(\d+(?:(?:\*|/|-|\+)\d+)*)`

But I guess, you want to keep the space between the expressions?

So what you could do is:

1. match everything what definitely is not a math expression (it's not a number and not an operator): `(?:[^\d+\-*/]+)`
2. match all operators which are not preceded by a number using 'negative lookbehind': `(?<!\d)[+\-*/]`
3. match all operators which are not followed by a number using 'negative lookahead': `[+\-*/](?!\d)`

And finally, you can combine all 3 of the above with `OR`:

`((?:[^\d+\-*/]+)|(?<!\d)[+\-*/]|[+\-*/](?!\d))`

This should match everything but the math expressions.